# Fill in and submit form with link outside this form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I would like to fill in **and** submit the follow form when clicking on a link outside the form, using the link's content.

```
<%= form_tag search_path, url: search_path, remote: true do %>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <div class='search-box'>
            <%= text_field_tag 'query', nil, class: 'form-control typeahead', autocomplete: 'off' %>
            </div>

            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#settingsmodal'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span>
                </button>
                <%= submit_tag t('process.search'), id: 'search_button', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </span>
        </div>
        <%= render 'settings_modal' %>
<% end %>

...

<a href="#">This text should be submitted</a>
```

I tried to fill in the text field and click the button using jQuery, but this didn't work. I read about the jQuery submit() call, but can't figure out how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add the text to the input box and submit the form

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('.search-box input').val($(this).html()); $('form').submit(); return false;">This text should be submitted</a>
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in my comment, the better way to do this would be in a JS file using IDs like this:

```
<form id="form-id">
    <input id="search-box-input" value="" />
</form>

<a href="#" id="link-id">This text should be submitted</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#link-id").click(function(){
            $('#search-box-input').val($(this).html()); 
            $('#form-id').submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Updated it to submit the form as well.  Technically, you probably want to assign an id to the form so you can access it with `$("#form_id").submit()`.    Also, if you assign the link a name, you can initialize the click function in a JS file, like this: `$("#link_id").click(function(){$('.search-box input').val($(this).html()); $('form').submit(); return false;});`

Comment: *Also, if you assign the link an *ID*

Comment: This should be working indeed, as I saw it on several other places. Unfortunately this is not the case for me... I can see the text field, but the form (having id 'form_id') is not submitted.

Comment: Can you post your actual rendered HTML?  Maybe duplicate the issue in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: `<input type="submit" form="form_id" />` is not working either

Comment: I updated my answer to show in the second part what the key pieces would look like with ids.

Comment: I found my problem! Submission of the form results in a .slideDown('slow') call on the result div. When I submit the form using jQuery these functions are not called and thus not show these results. Thanks for your work!